# How can I add a Number and Decimal keyboard into my Custom Keyboard on iOS8?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I created a custom keyboard in Swift but it was rejected from the App Store because: "keyboard extension does not include Number and Decimal types".

How can I add these two keyboards easily?

I tried to rebuild the original view but it doesn't work properly. I'm sure there is a solution to create 2 or 3 different views and switch between them.

How can I switch between keyboard types when the keyboard type changes?

Answer (score 4):

You can detect changes to the keyboard type in `textDidChange`. You need to get the `UITextDocumentProxy` then detect the proxy's `keyboardType`, and then you can do whatever layout changes needed.

```
override func textDidChange(_ textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // Called when the document context is changed - theme or keyboard type changes

    let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
    if proxy.keyboardType == UIKeyboardType.numberPad
        || proxy.keyboardType == UIKeyboardType.decimalPad {
        //add code here to display number/decimal input keyboard
    }
}
```